# is it possible to develop an app that will track other apps usage?

Tags: ios

I'm interested to know if it's possible to develop an similar app for iOS like this one that his just been release for android this week:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appuccino.frequencyfree

the app track other apps usage tracking and show the user how much time he spend on each app.

thanks.

Comment: No this isn't possible, Apple will not allow this as every app works in a sandboxed mode so it doesn't know about other apps on the device.

Answer (score 2):

No this isn't possible, Apple will not allow this as every app works in a sandboxed mode so it doesn't know about other apps on the device and will be rejected under:

> 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Of the App[le Review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)